# How can I fit a short loop on to one line?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a short loop like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    print "Hello"
```

How, if possible, can I fit this onto one line?

Comment: Why would you want to? You can, in this case, because you can inline a one-line statement block, just make it one line.

Comment: Read the first section on https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html; you can 'inline' simple statements under a compound statement. You cannot do that the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How, if possible, can I fit this onto one line?

You *can* just place it on a single line:

```
for i in range(10): print "Hello"
```

But that doesn't do you much, and goes against convention. You shouldn't try to cram many things onto one line when there's no reason to ([readability counts!](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

As an aside, generally `_` is used as the loop control variable when it's never needed in the loop's body:

```
for _ in range(10):
    print "Hello"
```

Comment: The only making a loop smaller is if you have many small loops in a script, you could take a line off all of them, it's just a way to make code shorter.

Comment: @SomeGuy What benefit is there in having fewer lines? You *really* should favor readability over shortness.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the statement right after the `:`.

```
for i in range(10):  print "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative - use `map`

(You tagged it as Python 2.7, so we do not have print as function initially)

Assuming you want to apply a function on each element in the list, `map` will loop over.

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Now I have `print` defined as a function and have the list to loop over:

```
>>> map(print, lst)
a
b
c
[None, None, None]
```

The `[None, None, None] is list of results, which is`None` in case of print. Returning a list costs some time. Depending of further use of the results it can be small advantage or disadvantage.

Note, that in Python 3 the `map` behaves a bit differently, it returns special sort of result of type `map` which has to be forced to iterate, e.g. by placing into `list` call. But this is not in scope of your question.

Comment: This can also be achieved with print_function and `[print('hello') for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: @TimCastelijns Why would you prefer that over a regular `for` loop? You're using a list comprehension for the side effect. This answer uses map for the side effect, which I also think is bad.

Comment: @arshajii I don't, just wanted to mention another way to get this result :-)